# Instead of Hop can only Ginger or Orange Peel be used for brewing Pure Wheat Beer?

Tags: first-time-brewer

I want to brew my first batch of pure wheat beer. But instead of Hop I want to use either dried orange peel or freshly grated ginger. Kindly suggest what to use and in what quantity should I use and when should I add those.....

Answer (score 1):

For 24 liters of wheat beer (like "Hoegarden") I used 10 - 14 g of dried bitter orange peel with 7g of fresh coriander seed from the kitchen garden. I have not used ginger in beer, but for ginger flavored drinks I find 1 teaspoon for 5 Litres gives the drink a slight warmth - so 5 teaspoons of ginger for 24 L would be a useful place to start. I am sure others would double or triple that amount!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. So if I have got it right that instead of using hop pellet I can use 14 gm of orange peel with 7 gm coriander seed.

Comment: Normally you would use orange peel and coriander in addition to hop. Without hop your beer will probably not keep very long. However, if you do not want hop bitter I suggest you add hops only to get an IBU of 20.

Comment: For how long then we can preserve it without using hop....

Comment: I have made unhopped wheat beer using coriander and orange peel and I kept it in bottles for 6 months or so. It might have kept longer but we drank it! :0)  IMHO, alcoholic yeast fermentations with dissolved CO2 are relatively stable in sealed, air-tight bottles.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If u could suggest what kind a yeast you have used and in what quantity. With that the temperature maintained during fermentation.

Comment: From memory I used either safale04 or 05(drier finish). I have also used Danstar "Nottingham". I tend to use safale04 for most beers. I have friends who use a lager yeast to ferment wheat beer - they say it gives a "crisp finish". Maybe....

Comment: So I understood about the yeast type but at what quantity should I use....

Comment: Start with 0,5 g per liter of wort. This would come down to 1 10 gram sachet of yeast for 20 l of beer. Since it is a light wheat beer, this would be fine to start with. If your batch is 25 l, keep it at one sachet. If you go higher in volume, I would recommend 2 sachets. Start with that for a first brew. Then search around on the net for brewing calculators or software, and read books and documentation about brewing.

Comment: As a guide you can use 11g for 24L of brew. Most home brewing yeasts come in 11g packets. That is approximately one table spoon full of yeast.Putting a bit more yeast into the brew (even twice as much) would not harm it but putting too little may slow the fermentation.

Comment: Thanks buddies a lot... Cleared my most of my queries...